# Как сделать проверку товара в каталоге есть ли он в корзине?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

как сделать проверку в каталоге если товар добавлен в корзину? Это нужно для того чтоб вывести определенный div на товаре если товар уже добавлен в корзину

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте такую функцию в functions.php:

```
function is_product_in_cart() {
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $cart_product = $values['data'];

        if( get_the_ID() == $cart_product->id ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Она возвращает true, если товар в корзине и false, если его там нет.

Дополнительно к вопросу поясняю, как вывести определённый div:

```
if ( is_product_in_cart() ) {
    // здесь выводите нужный вам <div>
} else {
    // здесь выводите другую информацию
}
```

Comment: что должно измениться? и как вывести его на карточку товара?

Comment: А как вы собирались выводить определённый div? Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Примерно так <? if ($carttrue>0): ?>
  //Если товар добавлен корзину выводим тут див с нужной инфой
 
<?else:?>
 //Если товар не добавлен в корзину выводим тут див с другой инфой
<?endif?>

Comment: Я расширил ответ, хотя это и выходит за рамки вопроса.